# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request when starting with jetty:run-forked and connecting with ssl

Tags: java, maven, classloader, jetty-9, maven-jetty-plugin

I'm using **jetty's pushbuilder** to push some resources. As these resources are specified from inside the webapp, i can't use jetty's default pushCacheFilter.

When i start jetty embedded from my main java-class, it works well, i can connect to my page with https and also the push works fine.

But when i start via jetty:run-forked, it starts and gives this output:

```
**Started ServerConnector@45b4c3a9{SSL,[http/1.1, ssl, alpn, h2]}{0.0.0.0:8443}**
```

And then when accessing the page i get this error:

```
**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:586)**
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.basex.http2.HTTP2Settings.push(HTTP2Settings.java:60)
at org.basex.http.HTTPConnection.initResponse(HTTPConnection.java:127)
at org.basex.http.restxq.RestXqResponse.serialize(RestXqResponse.java:209)
at org.basex.http.restxq.RestXqResponse.serialize(RestXqResponse.java:195)
at org.basex.http.restxq.RestXqResponse.create(RestXqResponse.java:97)
at org.basex.http.restxq.RestXqModule.process(RestXqModule.java:104)
at org.basex.http.restxq.RestXqFunction.process(RestXqFunction.java:109)
at org.basex.http.restxq.RestXqServlet.run(RestXqServlet.java:49)
at org.basex.http.BaseXServlet.service(BaseXServlet.java:59)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:833)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:206)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:219)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:564)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:317)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:289)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$3.succeeded(SslConnection.java:149)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable.invokePreferred(Invocable.java:128)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable$InvocableExecutor.invoke(Invocable.java:222)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:294)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:199)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:673)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:591)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Maybe it's sth. with the maven classloading?

**Edit**

Another error occurs: Some of my latest Code-Changes seem to be missing after the maven-build. I've tried to just run "maven clean", but there are still missing fields and an exception is thrown.

These fields also are found, when starting jetty embedded.

Thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

After reading the jetty-docs again i found the reason:

server-classes are hidden from the webapp if jetty is the servlet-container. So this was my fault, the exception had to be thrown! 
(see the docs here: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/jetty-classloading.html)

I think the other missing-field-exceptions were related to this "forbidden" import.

So i think my problem is another one:

**How can the (jetty-specific) serverPush can be realized, when it's not sure, that my webapp is deployed in jetty??**

Jetty's own solution (pushCacheFilter.java) doesn't fit my needs. 
So i guess i have to check, if i can write a filter that works in the moment when jetty sends the response.